# Show that $\mathfrak{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Textbook Text:

"In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, let $\mathfrak{R}$ be the collection of all rectangles of the type $(a_1, b_1] \times (a_2, b_2]$ where $-\infty \leq a_i < b_i \leq \infty$ for $i = 1, 2$ with the understanding that $(a_i, \infty] = (a_i, \infty)$.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the collection of all finite unions of members of $\mathfrak{R}$. We have $\mathfrak{R} \subset \mathfrak{A}$ since every $A \in \mathfrak{R}$ is the union of finitely many, actually one, members of $\mathfrak{R}$ so that $A \in \mathfrak{A}$.­ We regard $\emptyset$ as the union of 0 members of $\mathfrak{R}$ so that $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{A}$.

It is easily verified that $\mathfrak{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$."

---

Showing that $\mathfrak{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

1) A = $(-\infty, \infty] \times (-\infty, \infty] = \mathbb{R}^{2} \in \mathfrak{R}$, so $\mathbb{R}^{2} \in \mathfrak{A}$.

2) By definition, $\mathfrak{A}$ is the collection of finite unions of members of $\mathfrak{R}$. So, let $C = \cup_{i=1}^{N_1} E_{i}, D = \cup_{i=1}^{N_2} F_{i}$ where $E, F$ are arbitrary collections of members of $\mathfrak{R}$. Then $C, D \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $ C \cup D = (\cup_{i=1}^{N} E_{i}) \cup (\cup_{i=1}^{N} F_{i}) \in \mathfrak{A}$.

3) Let $A \in \mathfrak{A}$. From 2), if $A, A^{c} \in \mathfrak{A}$ then $A \cup A^{c} = \mathbb{R}^{2} \in \mathfrak{A}$. So $A \in \mathfrak{A} \implies A^{c} \in \mathfrak{A}$.

Is this a correct proof to show that $\mathfrak{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Edit:

2nd Attempt on proving $A \in \mathfrak{A} \implies A^{c} \in \mathfrak{A}$

3) Let $A = \cup_{i=1}^{N} (a_{1i}, b_{2i}] \times (a_{2i}, b_{2i}]$

Then 
\begin{align*}
A^{c} &= \cap_{i=1}^{N} \Big[(a_{1i}, b_{1i}] \times (a_{2i}, b_{2i}]\Big]^{c}\\
      &= \cap_{i=1}^{N} (-\infty, a_{1i}] \cup (b_{1i}, \infty] \times (-\infty, a_{2i}] \cup (b_{2i}, \infty]\\
      &= (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{1i})] \cup ( \min_{i\in N}(b_{1i}), \infty] \times (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{2i})] \cup ( \min_{i\in N}(b_{2i}), \infty]\\
      &= (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{1i})] \times (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{2i})] \cup (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{1i})] \times (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(b_{2i})] \cup (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(b_{1i})] \times (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(a_{2i})] \cup (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(b_{1i})] \times (-\infty, \max_{i\in N}(b_{2i})]
\end{align*}

Therefore as $A^{c}$ is a finite union of rectangles,  $A \in \mathfrak{A} \implies A^{c} \in \mathfrak{A}$.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, do you go to UBC? I think we might know each other.

Comment: Hi @MathematicsStudent1122, unfortunately I'm on the other side of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algebra is closed by finite intersections.
The intersection of two rectangles is a rectangle.
Thus the intersection of two finite unions of rectangles is a finite union of intersections of two rectangles; hence a finite union of rectangles.

The complement of (a,b]×(c,d] is
(oo,a]×R $\cup$ (b,oo)×R $\cup$ R×(oo,c] $\cup$ R×(d,oo).
Thus the complement of a finite union of rectangles is the finite intersection of complements, which from above is a finite union of rectangles.

(-oo,oo]×(-oo,oo] = R$^2$ is incorrect.
The rectangles need to be defined to avoid that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by "those squares"?

Comment: Whoops.  See edit.

Comment: Hi @William Elliot, I've just constructed another argument based on what I've interpreted from your answer. Does this seem more correct?

Comment: @Darius.  Excessively complex.

Comment: @Darius.  See revision.

Comment: Hi @William Elliot, why isn't $(-\infty,\infty]×(-\infty, \infty] = \mathbb{R}^2$? I can't seem to find any resource that would help me see why that is the case...

Comment: @Darius.  oo not in R.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. It says that $(a_{i}, \infty]$ is equivalent to $(a_{i}, \infty)$ in the text that I linked. Does this not mean that $(-\infty, \infty] \times (-\infty, \infty]$ is equivalent to $(-\infty, \infty) \times (-\infty, \infty)$ and so $\pm\infty$ is not included in the cartesian product but every other point in the real plane is included? Is that not $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: (a,oo] /= (a,oo);   (a,oo] $\cap$ R = (a,oo) $\cap$ R.